# Footnotes with author-year inline citation

Tags: biblatex, footnotes

Presently, I am using per-page footnotes for my citations using:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad3,autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
\bibliography{refs}
\begin{document}
This is some text \autocite{johnson}.
\end{document}
```

And `refs.bib`:

```
@article{johnson,
author = {Johnson, Rebecca},
journal = {Nature},
title = {{An effective method for something-or-other.}},
year = {2011}
}
```

**Here's what I have now:**

> This was later shown to be an effective method¹.
>   Following this effort, later models have more accurately described the
>   data but have thus far not generated testable hypotheses.

Then in the footnotes for that page:

> ¹Johnson, Rebecca. "An effective method for something-or-other." Nature (2011).

**Here's what I want**

> This was later shown to be an effective method [Johnson 2011].
>   Following this effort, later models have more accurately described the
>   data but have thus far not generated testable hypotheses.

Then in the footnotes for that page:

> Johnson, Rebecca. "An effective method for something-or-other." Nature (2011).

In other words, I can either get only either:

- The footnote style I show above, with footnotes but with superscript numbers for the inline citation
- An author-year inline citation, but with a bibliography section at the end instead of per-page footnotes.

However, I want [last-name year] to appear as a per-page footnote (without superscript numbering).

Comment: Thanks. I added a complete example. I'm not using Biber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the style `authoryear` as a base and issue a fullcite in a special footnote with each cite.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\plainbibfn}[1]{\bibfootnotewrapper{#1}}

\newbibmacro*{spfullfoot}{%
  \let\@makefntext\plainbibfn
  \footnotetext{%
    \fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\brackcite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}%
   \usebibmacro{spfullfoot}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\makeatother
```

The cite command `\brackcite` is essentially `\parencite` with square brackets and `spfullfoot` thrown in. `spfullfoot` redefines the footnote appearance locally and issues a fullcite.

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[%
  style=authoryear,
  autocite=footnote,
  backend=biber,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\plainbibfn}[1]{\bibfootnotewrapper{#1}}

\newbibmacro*{spfullfoot}{%
  \let\@makefntext\plainbibfn
  \footnotetext{%
    \fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\brackcite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}%
   \usebibmacro{spfullfoot}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum \brackcite{sigfridsson} dolor\footnote{sit} amet. 
Lorem ipsum \brackcite{sigfridsson} dolor\footnote{sit} amet.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Maybe you are a bit happier with the result after adding

```
bibstyle=authortitle,
```

We can also only print the fullcite on the first cite, if we use `citetracker=true` and

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\brackcite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}%
   \ifciteseen{}{\usebibmacro{spfullfoot}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```