# (Author, Year) in text, full citation in footnote

Tags: biblatex, lyx, natbib, jurabib

My thesis supervisor wants the following format for citations :

> This is the body of the text (Author, 2018)<sup>1</sup>.
>
> ---
>
> 1. Guy Author, *Latex love*, 2018. DOI:89453XXX:547

Which combination of bib(la)tex/nat/jurabib/styles can achieve this ?

I could only find this related question : [Footnotes with author-year inline citation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274760/footnotes-with-author-year-inline-citation) but the footnotes don't have a number. Of course, the full citation should only appear in the footnote for the first occurence. I could insert all the footnotes manually but `\bibentry` doesn't work with natbib.

Other answers involve pages of macros to achieve very specific needs, but it should be doable 'natively', right? Also now I just get a numerical reference when I compile, even-though I am using Author-year style (https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeREq.jpg). I tried compiling several times, to no avail.

All help welcome.

Comment: `biblatex` is probably your best choice. You are not using `biblatex` at the moment, so while you are waiting for an answer you may want to check out how to get `biblatex` to work with LyX. LyX 2.3 (released this spring) has massively improved support for `biblatex`, so if you can upgrade, you may want to consider doing that (as always upgrades or updates shortly before a deadline can be ill-advised, you never know what breaks). For older versions of LyX you can have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/298382/35864. For LyX 2.3 see https://wiki.lyx.org/BibTeX/Biblatex

Comment: LyX 2.3 solves my problem. It has all the required bells and whistles in the Bibliography settings. Should I delete this question ?

Comment: No, please write an answer that describes what you did and how it solved your problem.

Comment: I will but I'm still trying to figure out how to get the authors' names in normal case and a comma afterwards. I have `(AUTHOR 2018)` (with weird kerning) and I'm aiming for `(Author, 2018)`.

Comment: Are you French by any chance? Then https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/438423/35864 should help. Otherwise it would help me to see an example of what you are doing and how it goes wrong, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864, https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: Indeed the capitalization of names is caused by the french language setting. `\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}` produces an error when placed in the preamble. MNWE : https://pastebin.com/raw/cjWJ1G9X -- I was able to get a comma by using `Biblatex (natbib mode)` as style format.

Comment: What error exactly? I suspect your `biblatex` version is outdated.

Comment: 'Undefined control sequence` upon parsing the command, and cascading errors from there. Apparently I'm using `Biblatex 3.11`, even-though I ran MikTex update before updating to `LyX 2.3`, so that could very well be it. I'll sort it out. In the meantime your answer is pretty good. I'll still post mine.

Comment: Mhhh, `biblatex` 3.11 is the current version. So that can't be it. Can you cite which command exactly is supposed to be undefined?

Comment: All of them, ha ha. Here's the relevant part of the log : https://pastebin.com/raw/zjKRz0cC I think it's because in Lyx the user can't put anything after \makeatother and before \begin{document}, unless they edit the LyX file directly.

Comment: Ah, I see. These things need to be loaded after `biblatex`. And `biblatex` is only loaded right before `\begin{document}`. Can you somehow tell LyX to move the `\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}` to after `\usepackage{biblatex}`?

Comment: The LyX file does not contain the latex source but commands which are used to generate the source. Depending on where I insert the line, I either get an error when opening the file with LyX or nothing at all. This is a question for the LyX forums. There's probably a way somewhere to pass this as an option. PS : This is like the longest comment thread on SE, right ?

Comment: Just installing LyX to see if there is a way to convince it to accept preamble options after it loads `biblatex`. But indeed I think this is something you should raise in a LyX forum regardless. If there is non good way, you may want to phrase this is a a feature request. It really is crucial for `biblatex`'s customisability to be able to insert code in the preamble after `biblatex` is loaded. And no, I don't think this is the longest comment thread, they often have the tendency to grow uncontrollably when I get involved ;-)

Comment: See the answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313150/prevent-lyx-from-automatically-including-packages and replace "graphicx" with "biblatex". Then you are responsible for loading `biblatex` in the preamble, and you can put whatever you want before it and after it.

Comment: But then the command `\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}` is still in the preamble, when it should be between the end of the preamble and the beginning of the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LyX 2.3 makes this a breeze. Just select your settings in the 'Bibliography' tab of the document settings.

[image: document settings]

To get a comma between author and date, use `Biblatex (natbib mode)`.

I then added the footnotes manually, which gave me more flexibility.

For a way to do all this automatically in LaTeX, check out meowe's answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what your professor seems to want, but it might be close enough

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber, citetracker]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newbibmacro{fullcite}{%
  \usedriver
    {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
    {\thefield{entrytype}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{footnote}{\mkbibfootnote{#1}}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\ffparencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}%
   \ifciteseen
     {}
     {\printtext[footnote]{\usebibmacro{fullcite}}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\ffparencites}[\mkbibparens]{\ffparencite}{\multicitedelim}

\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{inlineff}{\ffparencite}{\ffparencites}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{autocite=inlineff}

\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}

\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson} and \autocite{sigfridsson}

\autocite{nussbaum,geer}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The code automatically adds a footnote with the full reference on the first citation. The footnote is inside the brackets to give reasonable output for the case `\autocite{nussbaum,geer}`.

[image]

Alternatively,

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber, citetracker]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ffparenwrap}[1]{%
  \undef\blx@ffcite
  \mkbibparens{#1}%
  \ifundef\blx@ffcite
    {}
    {\footfullcite{\blx@ffcite}}%
}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\ffparencite}[\ffparenwrap]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}%
   \ifciteseen
     {}
     {\ifundef\blx@ffcite
        {\xdef\blx@ffcite{\thefield{entrykey}}}
        {\xappto\blx@ffcite{,\thefield{entrykey}}}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\makeatother

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\ffparencites}[\mkbibparens]{\ffparencite}{\multicitedelim}

\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{inlineff}{\ffparencite}{\ffparencites}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{autocite=inlineff}

\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}

\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson} and \autocite{sigfridsson}

\autocite{nussbaum,geer}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

makes sure that the footnote comes outside the round brackets. But it has to coerce several citations into one footnote to achieve this.

[image]

If you change `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` block to

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ffparenwrap}[1]{%
  \let\blx@ffcite\@empty
  \mkbibparens{#1}%
  \ifdefvoid\blx@ffcite
    {}
    {\forlistloop{\footfullcite}{\blx@ffcite}}%
}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\ffparencite}[\ffparenwrap]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}%
   \ifciteseen
     {}
     {\listxadd\blx@ffcite{\thefield{entrykey}}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\makeatother
```

the citations get a footnote each at the expense of possibly clashing footnotes.